# Rezize logical partitions (lvm) inside a LUKS encrypted partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm, luks

The root partition of my LUKS encrypted disk is getting full, so I want to increase its size. For that, I want to shrink the "home" partition and enlarge the "root" partition. I don´t want to increase the LUKS partition size per se as I have seen in a couple of tutorials, just adjust the size of its logical partitions.

I tried to follow [this](http://e1z.ca/devlog/encrypted_partition_resize.html) guide and use a Xubuntu Live CD and Install Partition Manager, but while I can decrypt the partition and see its logical partitions, I can´t change the sizes as they are greyed out in the application.

I could use the command line, but I am a little afraid to mess up my partitions, so would be nice if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Here what my partition scheme looks like:

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                       259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                                   259:1    0   200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                   259:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3                                   259:3    0 475,8G  0 part  
  └─luks-86ee1449-bae3-4e82-9465-432ca6457e2a 253:0    0 475,7G  0 crypt 
    ├─fedora_localhost--live-root             253:1    0    70G  0 lvm   /
    ├─fedora_localhost--live-swap             253:2    0   7,8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─fedora_localhost--live-home             253:3    0   398G  0 lvm   /home
```

I want to increase the `fedora_localhost--live-root` to at least 90GB and reduce the `fedora_localhost--live-home` accordingly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using [Blivet Gui](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Blivet-gui) on a Fedora live CD